# Adding bundle product programatically

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, programmatically

Using Magento 2.1.1. I have to add some bundle products programatically. Any post on stack doesn't work for me.

Here is my code - it adds bundle products with some options and every option should has only one selection. Althought it seems to work and options and selections are present in admin, saving from admin brakes product totally what indicates it was not added properly. If anyone has some working script for that please share.

Some example data:

```
$product['children'] = [
                        'name' => ['id' => 1345, 
                                   'license_extended_can_change_qty' => 1
                                  ], 
                                  ....
                       ];
```

Functions converting data to migrate for arrays used for adding bundle items:

```
private function prepareBundleOptionsMap($product)
{
    $bundle_options_map = array();

    foreach ($product['children'] as $childName => $childId) {
        $child_map = [
            'title' => $childName,
            'default_title' => $childName,
            'type' => 'select',
            'required' => 1,
            'delete' => '',
        ];

        $bundle_options_map[] = $child_map;
    }

    return $bundle_options_map;
}



private function prepareBundleSelectionsMap($product)
    {
    $bundle_selections_map = array();


    foreach ($product['children'] as $childName => $childData) {
        $child_map = [[
            'product_id' => $childData['id'],
            'selection_qty' => 1,
            'selection_can_change_qty' => $childData['license_extended_can_change_qty'],
            'delete' => '',
            'user_defined' => $childData['license_extended_can_change_qty']
        ]];

        $bundle_selections_map[] = $child_map;

        if ($childData['status'] == Status::STATUS_DISABLED) {
            $this->_logger->addInfo(__(' Bundle ' . $product['title'] . ' - one of children is disabled: ' . $childData['name']));
        }
    }

    return $bundle_selections_map;
}
```

And fragment of bigger script using above methods:

```
$bundle_options_map = $this->prepareBundleOptionsMap($migrated_product);
$bundle_selections_map = $this->prepareBundleSelectionsMap($migrated_product);

    $product->setBundleOptionsData($bundle_options_map);
    $product->setBundleSelectionsData($bundle_selections_map);

    if ($product->getBundleOptionsData()) {
        $options = [];
        foreach ($product->getBundleOptionsData() as $key => $optionData) {
            if (!(bool)$optionData['delete']) {
                $option = $this->optionFactory->create(['data' => $optionData]);
                $option->setSku($product->getSku());
                $option->setOptionId(null);

                $links = [];
                $bundleLinks = $product->getBundleSelectionsData();
                if (!empty($bundleLinks[$key])) {
                    foreach ($bundleLinks[$key] as $linkData) {
                        if (!(bool)$linkData['delete']) {
                            $link = $this->linkFactory->create(['data' => $linkData]);
                            $linkProduct = $this->productRepository->getById($linkData['product_id']);
                            $link->setSku($linkProduct->getSku());
                            $link->setQty($linkData['selection_qty']);
                            $link->setCanChangeQuantity($linkData['selection_can_change_qty']);
                            $links[] = $link;
                        }
                    }
                    $option->setProductLinks($links);
                    $options[] = $option;
                }
            }
        }
        $extension = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extension->setBundleProductOptions($options);
        $product->setExtensionAttributes($extension);
        $product->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here was not to use `$product->save()`, but instead save product via `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php::save()` method. It caused for me some issue with saving images programatically, so I haven't use it before. It turned out that my saving images was also deprecated - so preferably this script more or less should work, just with this little change.

Using deprecated `save()` product bundle options will collapse totally when later it would be saved from adminhtml.